# Export predictions of rolling-regression in a data.frame

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I want to add the predictions of the `roll_lm` function from the [roll](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roll/roll.pdf) package in a `data.frame` (let's say *p_df*). It might be a very easy task but I can't find how to do it.

This is what I have done so far:

```
library(roll)

x <- as.matrix(test[, 2:3])
y <- test[, 1]

m <- roll_lm(x = x, y = y, width = 5, complete_obs = TRUE)
```

From here, how can I extract the predictions? In base `R`, the predictions of a linear model can be obtained by using the `predict` function. What is the equivalent of the `roll` package?

Here is a small data set:

```
test <- structure(list(ntl = c(9.14866638183594, 15.3856477737427, 16.3302040100098, 
12.454291343689, 10.4823837280273, 11.394606590271, 8.1963529586792, 
4.50725030899048, 3.95374751091003, 5.73203563690186, 14.3955335617065, 
17.0745468139648, 14.2944135665894, 10.333722114563, 9.80743503570557, 
12.5352020263672, 19.8813304901123, 29.2410221099854, 32.8321876525879, 
29.575023651123), pop = c(31.2753772735596, 55.8289375305176, 
56.4003105163574, 33.795223236084, 31.0511913299561, 30.5730743408203, 
13.667106628418, 7.08161020278931, 6.89333772659302, 13.9001550674438, 
35.5272178649902, 42.4625587463379, 32.9688529968262, 21.4302787780762, 
12.6151924133301, 17.4939270019531, 38.1474113464355, 60.8120536804199, 
65.3665008544922, 53.8765907287598), tirs = c(30.9432029724121, 
31.7461566925049, 32.6338005065918, 32.6965866088867, 31.9309749603271, 
33.7227897644043, 31.1048107147217, 30.1847438812256, 30.2888336181641, 
33.8297653198242, 33.7649192810059, 32.5485496520996, 31.0377178192139, 
30.5556716918945, 30.0720176696777, 29.4081420898438, 31.0848445892334, 
33.8344841003418, 34.1492614746094, 32.9989166259766)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```